# How to update deleted row in datagridview by using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am a beginner of vb.net. Recently I encountering a very strange problem on datagridview.
Here's my code:

```
Public Class testing
Dim bm As BindingManagerBase
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow

Private Sub testing_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11)
    bm = Me.BindingContext(DataSet11, "calculatetable")
End Sub

Public Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    a = 0
    OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet11, "calculatetable")
    dt = DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable")
    max = dt.Rows.Count - 1
    For len As Integer = 0 To max
        dr = dt.Rows(len)
        a = dr("Number") + a
    Next
    Label1.Text = a
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    dt = DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable")
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = TextBox1.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    dt = DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable")
    dr = dt.Rows.Find(TextBox1.Text)
    dr.Delete()
End Sub
End Class
```

Actually, I am trying to do a calculating table for my cashier system project. I have a textbox for user to enter number for adding new data in new row and delete the selected row.
In my database, I have a table named "calculatetable" and have one column named "Number" with Primary key in it.
Both add function and delete function must updated into database. 
The add function seems doing well but the delete function makes me headache...
I got this error message:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Table doesn't have a primary key."
```

Is there any problem on my coding? Or I missed any part to make this success? And sorry for my bad english :) Thank you.

Comment: Seems like this could be your issue: [Read Me!!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx) assuming your table actually DOES have a `Primary Key`

Comment: You load your datatable from a table in sql server but you don't specify the primarykey of the datatable. Notice that the parameter to the Find method is the key of the datatable, but since you didn't specify the primary key it will fail. You probably just need to look at the link posted above and find your row another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, the issue stems from not having a primary key on that table. To alleviate this issue, you can define your primary key column easily. When you define your column, then the `Rows.Find` method knows exactly what row you want to remove.

You can also use the `DataTable.Select` function without a primary key, *but if per say the number is in another row it wont remove it*. For example: Say you have 3 rows with Id's 1,12,32. If you use the select function and wanted to remove 12 from the list it wont work because 2 exists in 32.

**Add primary key to your table...**

```
 DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable").Columns("YOURUNIQUECOLUMN")}
```

You can do this on the load, this way your datatable has it's primary key upfront. Where it says "YOURUNIQUECOLUMN", this is where you would specify your column that is unique; usually an id column of some sort. When you have this done, you can remove the row...

```
 dr = DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable").Rows.Find(TextBox1.Text)

 If dr IsNot Nothing Then
  DataSet11.Tables("calculatetable").Rows.Remove(dr)
 End If
```

Comment: @Villager A, it looks like you may be new here at SO. If this question helped your issue please mark this answer by checking the check mark by my answer so other's know that this was answered. Thanks!